# progress bar in windows application in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, progress-bar

I have progress bar that style should be continuous. and i am using progress bar on login form. and check username and password from web service. How i add progress bar for that.

Comment: Are you using WPF, WinForms, Silverlight or ASP.NET?

Comment: I think it's not useful. If (as I think) webservice gets your request and sends a response, your ProgressBar should go from 0 (sending request) to 100 (response received) without middle steps...

Answer (score 0):

use the Progress bar control in the Gui designer.
The value you should use is anywhere from 0 to 1. this is converted to percents.
like 0.1 is 10%, 0.25 is 25%.
You can also set the min and max value and just use value++ on it to make it work.